# Creating Nested Lists

Tags: java

How do I create nested lists in java? so I have a factory method below which will pass a list to the constructor of the ROOM class. But I need to associate each wall with a window, So when I iterate over the list in the constructor it knows that a certain window belongs to a certain wall?.

```
public static Room RoomU(){
    List<Room> RoomU = new ArrayList<Room>();

    // THESE TWO SHOULD BE PAIRED AND SO ON...
    RoomU.add(new Walls(Height, Width));
    RoomU.add(new Windows(Height,Width));

    RoomU.add(new Walls(Height, Width));
    RoomU.add(new Windows(Height,Width));

    RoomU.add(new Walls(Height, Width));
    RoomU.add(new Windows(Height,Width));

    RoomU.add(new Walls(Height, Width));
    RoomU.add(new Windows(Height,Width));

    RoomU.add(new Walls(Height, Width));
    RoomU.add(new Windows(Height,Width));

    return new Room(RoomU);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), not List.

```
Map<Walls, Windows> myMAp = new HashMap<Walls, Windows>();
mMap.put(new Walls(1,2), new Windows(1,2));
```

Looking at this again, I think that maybe you should refactor some more basic thing, and have the windows object inside the walls object:

```
List<Walls> rooms = new ArrayList<Walls>();
rooms.add(new Walls(1,2,new Windows(1,2)));

//--- in Walls class:
Windows windows;

public Walls(int height, int width, Windows windows) {
    this.windows = windows;
    // the rest
}
```

Comment: It's method `put`, `add` didn't exist for Map.

Answer (score 0):

For the use case you describe, the best approach would be to use a `Map<Walls, Windows>`.

Answer (score 0):

your `Room` class needs a `Collection` of `Wall` objects.

```
class Room  
{  
   Collection<Wall> walls;  
   ...
}    

class Wall  
{  
    String side;    
    Collection<Window> windows;
    ...
}
```

You can then iterate over the `walls` and determine which `side` they are on.

```
for(Wall wall : walls)  
{  
    wall.getSide();  
    //do stuff with side
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `Windows` a property of `Walls`?

```
Windows w = new Windows(height,width);
RoomU.add(new Walls(height, width, w));
                                // ^ seems more object-oriented
```